# access grunt initConfig block within registerTask

Tags: gruntjs

I have a function that is passed to registerTask, I want to know if I can access the initConfig block from within it:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    foo: 'bar'
    ...
});

grunt.registerTask('deploy', "Deploy web app", function(){
    grunt.task.run('shell:create_temp');
    //access init.foo configuration here
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:

```
    grunt.config.get('foo');
```